# Proxy JBoss HTTP with Apache HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, jboss, proxy

I have an application running in JBoss 7 AS and I would like to front it with Apache HTTPD on the same server.

The application is running in HTTP and I would like to have Apache on HTTPS.
So, all requests beginning with `https://myserver.mydomain/jboss_app` should be redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/jboss_app` appropriately.

I have installed the SSL certificate on Apache.

1. Do I need to install it on JBoss also?
2. What would the rewrite rule
   look like?
3. Or, is it something else that I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself.

1. We do not need to install the certificate on JBoss.
2. There is no rewrite rule change from what we did when we front end with `http`,
   except that we need to mention that the redirection is from `https`.
3. We need to take care that the application is written / configured
   properly to support such redirections. (This was specifically the
   problem with my configuration).